# Pythagorean spiral: Problem with \foreach and \pgfmathresult?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

The code below shows the problem. There are two `tikzpicture`s. The first is the code expanded and this works. The second is the same code but put within a `\foreach` loop. This doesn't work.

I assume that there is something happening to either the evaluation of the index `\n` or the use of `\pgfmathresult` within the `\foreach` loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A0) at (1,0);
\pgfmathparse{add(90,0)}; 
%
\path (A0) ++ (\pgfmathresult:1) coordinate (A1);
\draw (O)--(A0)--(A1)--(O);
\coordinate (A0) at (A1);
\pgfmathparse{add(\pgfmathresult,atan(1/sqrt(1)))};
%
\path (A0) ++ (\pgfmathresult:1) coordinate (A1);
\draw (O)--(A0)--(A1)--(O);
\coordinate (A0) at (A1);
\pgfmathparse{add(\pgfmathresult,atan(1/sqrt(2)))};
%
\path (A0) ++ (\pgfmathresult:1) coordinate (A1);
\draw (O)--(A0)--(A1)--(O);
\coordinate (A0) at (A1);
\pgfmathparse{add(\pgfmathresult,atan(1/sqrt(3)))};
%
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A0) at (1,0);
\pgfmathparse{add(90,0)}; 
%
\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{
\path (A0) ++ (\pgfmathresult:1) coordinate (A1);
\draw (O)--(A0)--(A1)--(O);
\coordinate (A0) at (A1);
\pgfmathparse{add(\pgfmathresult,atan(1/sqrt(\n)))}; 
}
%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the value of `\pgfmathresult` in a global variable since you are doing the derivations within a block of `{...}`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A0) at (1,0);
\pgfmathparse{add(90,0)};
\edef\res{\pgfmathresult}
%
\foreach \n in {1,2,...,10}{
  \path (A0) ++ (\res:1) coordinate (A1);
  \draw (O)--(A0)--(A1)--(O);
  \coordinate (A0) at (A1);
  \pgfmathparse{add(\res,atan(1/sqrt(\n)))};
  \xdef\res{\pgfmathresult};
} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]